# Marcar perguntas para responder em outro momento

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

Poderia existir um novo recurso que eu pudesse marcar uma pergunta como "pendente" para eu responde-lá posteriormente?

> Possivelmente posso fazer isso com o uso da funcionalidade
>   "Favoritos", porém, acredito que não foi criada para isso.

### Meu motivo

Em determinadas situações, o [perguntador criou um caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176668/form-transparente-com-imagem-c) (do meu interesse, inclusive até sei responder) mas, no devido instante, não poderei reproduzir/ajudar. Gostaria de acompanhar estas perguntas e num momento oportuno (se ainda não foi respondida adequadamente) criar a resposta.

A cada pergunta nova no site nestas condições, eu adiciona-las-ia em minha lista de pendências e não perderia tempo realizando novos filtros repetidas vezes.

### Para debate

Como sugestão - ainda, esta lista poderia ser pública, permitindo ao perguntador saber quantos se interessaram por seu problema, por exemplo. Também mostraria o comprometimento dos usuários com as questões sem resposta.

Comment: Só usar o recurso de favoritos. Acho que ele atende a isso.

Comment: Tenho o mesmo problema que você. Concordo com tudo.

Comment: Eu acho que mais do que uma ferramenta somente para isso é que deveria haver um sistema de notificações internas agendadas, isso para qualquer tarefa, a agenda não funcionaria só por data, mas também por ação. Outra coisa é que perguntas favoritadas poderiam nos notificar se houve-se atualizações ou novas respostas, como se fosse um "Seguir"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu não acho uma má ideia, ou uma necessidade inexistente, mas não vejo como o recurso de Favoritos deixa de atender a isso.

Se todo o necessário pra resolver o problema é uma ferramenta que te permita marcar um post de caráter excepcional, vasculhar a lista mais tarde, e agir sobre ela... O ato de favoritar (e eventualmente desfavoritar, se for o caso) é perfeitamente cabível.

Como eu disse, não é uma má ideia ou sem propósito, mas é essencialmente uma funcionalidade quase totalmente similar a uma que já temos só que com semântica diferente.

Comment: Ao perguntar estava bem ciente dos recursos possíveis do "favoritos", no entanto, achei importante perguntar sobre uma nova ferramenta. Mesmo sempre acompanhando o Meta, fiquei na dúvida.

Comment: @ismael Sem problema. O fato da ideia ganhar [tag:status-recusado] não significa que não devia ter sido sugerida, ou até mesmo que é uma má ideia. Há muita coisa pra se fazer no site, e não temos condição de implementar tudo...

Answer (score 7):

Favorito é o que tem, e duvido que exista vantagem ou mesmo necessidade para outro mecanismo. É uma situação que é muito exceção e que idealmente nem deveria existir. Quase não será usado.

Em raro caso que aconteceu comigo deixei a aba aberta porque é a única forma que eu sei que vou lembrar de responder mesmo.

Já pediram até mesmo para poder ter algum tipo de classificação dos favoritos e foi declinado.

Na verdade em grande parte das vezes está perdendo uma oportunidade em não responder na hora.

O caminho é ele mesmo, ou até ter um controle fora do site. Parece muito trabalho para um uso muito específico, tem coisas mais importantes para implementar.

Minha opinião é para priorizar outra coisa.

Comment: Sobre responder na hora, é que não é possível mesmo. Nem ficar com a pergunta aberta, já que mais uso o SOpt durante o expediente do que em casa. Obrigado.

Comment: Discordo. Para mim seria bastante útil. Agora quanto a se/quando vão fazer uma coisa dessas, sei que dificilmente iriam atender a isto, mas me ajudaria bastante.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Claramente ela nos seria útil, inclusive, poderia ser também um dia a outros que neste momento não seja.

Comment: Eu normalmente uso o que o navegador já tem pronto. Os bookmarks. Dependendo como a pessoa usa, dá até pra sincronizar o de casa com o trabalho. Ou quem sabe mandar o link por email pra abrir em casa, se não quiser misturar. Acho que tem muitas maneiras bem simples de resolver isso (ao menos eu faço isso o tempo todo e funciona, mas vai de cada um).